# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone with pytube version 12.0.0

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytube

Im trying to run a youtube downloader with flask and pytube. I programmed it on my windows Pc and everything works fine but now when I try to use the site on my ubuntu server it gives me this error:
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone

Its the same error like in other Posts but, the solution following to the answers is installing version 11.0.0.
But I tryied version 11.0.0 and 12.0.0 and it only works on my Pc(Windows).

Maybe u know the problem.